# Optimizing concave function over non-convex set

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have the following problem that I am looking advice on. Let $ \mathcal{F}$ be a convex subset of vector space $X$. The goal it to 
\begin{align*}
\max_{x \in \mathcal{F}} f(x)\\
s.t. \ g(x) \le 0
\end{align*}

Also $f(x)$ is strictly concave and continuos over $\mathcal{F}$. However, the function $g(x)$ is continuos and  concave.

So, the set formed by $\Omega= \mathcal{F} \cap \{x: g(x) \le 0 \}$ is not convex in general.

Clearly, this problem does not fall under umbrella of convex optimization.

Since the set $\Omega$ is compact $f(x)$ attains its maximum.

However, I am not sure how to find optimizing $x^*$.

**Main Question:** The frist step I thought is to pose Lagrangian (KKT).
But my question is can I even pose a Lagrangian (KKT) as a necessary  condition?
For example does $\Omega$ have to be convex to pose KKT?

For, example are there any references (books or papers) you can point me to learn about something similar?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The problem is generically intractable, so you would have to give a lot more information on $f$ and $\Omega$ to identify a problem which actually might be solvable

Comment: Sure, one of the example I am considering is: $f$ is differential entropy and $X$ is the space of probability distributions that have density.

Comment: If you can come out with a convex relaxation of $\Omega$ you have a tractable problem that will attain a unique solution. That solution is also an upper bound for the actual problem.

Comment: @AC_MOSEK Thanks a lot. Could you point me to these method of relaxation?

Comment: hard to give precise pointers, it really depends on the definition of $\Omega$....some search on Google Scholar would do the trick I think

Comment: @AC_MOSEK I have reformulated the problem a little bit. Do you think for this versin I can pose KKT as necessary condition?